# WordPress Plugin Activation triggers a Fatal Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I know there are many questions like this but I couldn't find any that pinged on the specifics relevant to my case. Either that or they went unanswered.

I've written a pretty simple PHP script and uploaded to a wordPress site in a zip folder and when I try to activate the plugin, WordPress gives me a message reading: "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error." It does not actually give me any error message. I have WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_LOG, and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY all set to true, but none of these are updated upon the supposed error. It seems I have no way of finding out what exactly the fatal error is.

I'm kind've at a loss as to how to proceed with this problem. Any help would be useful.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Denrile's Plogger
Plugin URI: http://my-awesomeness-emporium.com
description: >- a plugin to that takes the user to the Pruvan website,
after using CURL to log them in so that the redirect doesn't hit a user authentication wall.
Version: 1.0
Author: John Mauran
Author URI: http://github.com/jmauran91
License: GPL2
*/

  $j_username = "Denrile";
  $j_password = "*************";
  $login_url ="https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/login";
  $last_url = "https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/pmgr";


  function loginToJulian($url, $username, $password){
    $curl = curl_init();
    $header[0]= "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $verbose = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
    // Make the errors visible in a new file

    $payload_username = '"'.$username.'"';
    $payload_password = '"'.$password.'"';
    $payloadtext=urlencode('{"username":'.$payload_username.',"password":'.$payload_password.'}');
    $payload = "payload=".$payloadtext;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $store = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($store);
  }

  if(isset($_GET['prvn_login'])){
    loginToJulian($login_url, $j_username, $j_password);
    header("Location: https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/pmgr");
    exit();
  }
  else{

    exit();
  }

?>
```

The general idea of this plugin is that it will hook into a javascript-generated A-tag on the WordPress site, CURL Post to another site to login, and then re-direct to that site, hopefully bypassing the user authentication since the user will already be logged in thanks to the CURL.

Comment: Is your `wp-content` folder writable? If so, you should have a `debug.log` file in there. Did you check it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me.
But one question, Why you added exit(); inside the else condition, It is breaking the plugin activation process.

Please check and let me know.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Denrile's Plogger
Plugin URI: http://my-awesomeness-emporium.com
description: >- a plugin to that takes the user to the Pruvan website,
after using CURL to log them in so that the redirect doesn't hit a user authentication wall.
Version: 1.0
Author: John Mauran
Author URI: http://github.com/jmauran91
License: GPL2
*/

  $j_username = "Denrile";
  $j_password = "*************";
  $login_url ="https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/login";
  $last_url = "https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/pmgr";


  function loginToJulian($url, $username, $password){
    $curl = curl_init();
    $header[0]= "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $verbose = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
    // Make the errors visible in a new file

    $payload_username = '"'.$username.'"';
    $payload_password = '"'.$password.'"';
    $payloadtext=urlencode('{"username":'.$payload_username.',"password":'.$payload_password.'}');
    $payload = "payload=".$payloadtext;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $store = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($store);
  }


  function default_wordpress_hook(){
    if(isset($_GET['prvn_login'])){
      loginToJulian($login_url, $j_username, $j_password);
      header("Location: https://titlereporter.direct.pruvan.com/v2/pmgr");
      exit();
    } else {

    }  
  }
  add_action("init","default_wordpress_hook");

?>
```

Comment: thank you, that worked, although I don't understand why / why mine didn't work?